# Open MatDialog via dynamically added 'Click' event to an element

Tags: click, angular9, mat-dialog

I have an HTML list where I set .active class dynamically. Those elements that have this class need to have a 'Click' event that opens MatDialog. The problem is that I'm getting an error when trying to do something like that:

Angular component .html file

```html
<ul>
  <li><span id="asd">asd</span></li>
</ul>
```

Angular component .ts file

```js
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
...
...
this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#asd').addEventListener('click', this.selectTimeslot);
...
...
selectTimeslot() {
  let asd2: MatDialogRef<CalendarDialogComponent, any> = this.asd.open(CalendarDialogComponent, { disableClose: true });

  asd2.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
  });
}
```

Then when I click an element of the list I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Everything is working fine when I statically declare (click) directive inside HTML like that:

```html
<ul>
  <li><span (click)="selectTimeslot()">asd</span></li>
</ul>
```

How I can dynamically add a click event to the span element and be able to open the MatDialog component in the Angular 9? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution myself. This was a classical "*this* context" problem.

```js
let self = this;
..
..
this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#asd').addEventListener('click', function() { self.selectTimeslot(this););
```

At the beginning of the function, I've created a new variable, which points to the context of the Angular component. Then as a parameter, I'm passing the context of the "click event".